# iOS 13 and input of type password

Tags: mobile, ios13

We've recently come across an issue (specifically concerning iOS 13) on iphones and itablets where the keyboard consistently becomes hidden upon focus in an input of type password.

The issue is repeatable on multiple sites that have a password input, but I can find no trace of the issue, or a resolution, online.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Same issue, did you manage to resolve?